# sorting vector<variant<...>> does not work correctly via operator<

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I wanted to sort a std::vector of type std::variant with two custom classes by their member return value. See code below.

Now, using

```
std::sort(std::begin(shapes), std::end(shapes), [](auto const& a, auto const& b){
        return std::visit([](auto const& s) { return s.area(); }, a)
            < std::visit([](auto const& s) { return s.area(); }, b);
        });
```

does seem to work, but it is very ugly. Since std::variants operator< operates on their respective values I thought supplying a templated comparison operator would look better. But why does it not work?

## Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

constexpr double pi = 3.141592865;

struct Square {
    double d{};
    double area() const { return d * d; }
};

struct Circle {
    double r{};
    double area() const { return pi * r * r; }
};

// comparison operator for using std::sort(begin, end);
template <class S, class T>
double operator<(S const& a, T const& b) {
    return a.area() < b.area();
}

int main (int, char**)
{
    std::vector<std::variant<Square, Circle>> shapes;

    shapes.push_back(Circle{2});
    shapes.push_back(Square{2});
    shapes.push_back(Circle{1});
    shapes.push_back(Square{3});

    for (auto const& e: shapes)
    { std::cout << std::visit([](auto const& x) { return x.area(); }, e) << "\n"; }

    std::cout << "\n[SORT]\n\n";
    // Does not work
    std::sort(std::begin(shapes), std::end(shapes));

    /* works
    std::sort(std::begin(shapes), std::end(shapes), [](auto const& a, auto const& b){
            return std::visit([](auto const& s) { return s.area(); }, a)
                < std::visit([](auto const& s) { return s.area(); }, b);
            });
    */

    for (auto const& e: shapes)
    { std::cout << std::visit([](auto const& x) { return x.area(); }, e) << "\n"; }

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? I suspect the problem lies within the *operator<* not working with different types.

**Compilation command:**
    $ g++8.2 -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test

**Output:**

```
12.5664
4
3.14159
9

[SORT]

4
9
3.14159
12.5664
```

Weirdly, I run into compilation errors when using godbolts compile explorer and g++8.2, *but* not when using g++ trunk. See: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tKJa4t

Comment: Pretty sure that variant's comparison overload compares ***which*** alternatives are in both variants, and then compares them directly only if both variants have the same underlying type. I.e. it compares `index`() first.

Comment: FWIW, [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) can visit multiple variants at once, so that first snippet can be `std::visit([](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs) { return lhs.area() < rhs.area(); }, a, b)`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah, I see. I guess that settles it, I have to use std::visit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
std::sort(std::begin(shapes), std::end(shapes));
```

uses the default `sort` comparison, which is `operator<`. `operator<` on `std::variant` is [defined as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator_cmp) comparing on indices *first* and then, if the two variants hold the same alternative, comparing the underlying values.

In other words:

```
using V = std::variant<char, int>;
V v1(static_cast<char>(42));  // holds a char
V v2(15);                     // holds an int
v1 < v2;                      // this is true, because 'char' comes before 'int'
```

So when you sort your `variant`s, you're not sorting by area. You're effectively sorting by the tuple `(index, area)`. Which we could write out the long way:

```
std::sort(std::begin(shapes), std::end(shapes),
    [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs)
    {
        auto tied = [](auto const& x) {
            return std::make_tuple(
                // the index
                x.index(),
                // the area
                std::visit([](auto const& e){ return e.area(); }, x)
                );
        };
        return tied(lhs) < tied(rhs);
    });
```

This gives the same ordering as your original example. And then if you remove the `x.index()` part of the tuple, you'll get the ordering that you want.

But it's shorter to just use multiple visitation:

```
std::sort(std::begin(shapes), std::end(shapes),
    [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs)
    {
        std::visit([](auto const& x, auto const& y){
            return x.area() < y.area();
        }, lhs, rhs);
    });
```

Which will become shorter still in C++20 with Ranges and projections:

```
std::ranges::sort(shapes, std::less(), [](auto const& x){
    return std::visit([](auto const& e){ return e.area(); }, x);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how `std::variant`'s `operator<` works. It first compares indexes, and only if indexes are equal, it compares the values: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator_cmp. For unequal indexes, it returns `true` if index on the first variant is smaller than on second.